# What is leaflet-src.map?

Tags: leaflet, javascript, web-mapping, mapping, html

I've download the Leaflet package and there is "leaflet-src.map"

What is it exactly? Do I need it to use Leaflet correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a [*source map*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Use_a_source_map), it is just a debugging utility file.

No, you do not need it to use Leaflet, unless you have some errors and you need to inspect where they come from.